# Issue with iPhone with different Bluetooth scan result

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, macos, bluetooth

I've developed an application for iPhone to scan BLE devices. My configuration is:
iogear with PC running Debian;
iogear with iMac;
iogear with MacbookAir;
iPhone 4s;
iPhone 5;

Now when i run a scanning of BLE devices i find on different iPhone ( 4s/5 ) different result, in particular i find the 3 devices but iPhones show different name and different uuid for the same BLE device.

How is it possible?!

Comment: The UUID shown is a mix between the MAC Adress, a timeStamp and the MacAdress of the listener.

Comment: And for the name? Iphone 4s find iogear1 and call it null, Iphone 5 find same iogear1 and call it iogear1NAME

Comment: It reads this information piece by piece. For most of my use cases, if the device has no name, I don't show it. Sometimes, I also check if the advertisment data contains a key.. It should pass again the the `didDiscoverPeripheral` after with potentially a name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.   The control about the name is implemented in the application, but this is the problem, the iPhone 5 shows devices name, iPhone4s doesn't shows name, so i have to exclude devices on iPhone4s that i don't exclude on iPhone5